# Authenticate method has stopped working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an application in Django that worked perfectly until I tried what this guide says: https://scribles.net/deploying-existing-django-app-to-heroku/

Now when I try to log in with a user, it always returns a NonType

The application opens normally, I can recover the password, modify it.... but do not log in.

The DB contains the user, so it has not been deleted.

When I execute the following statement in the django shell I get the following:

```
user = authenticate(username='email@gmail.com', password='1234')
user.name
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

```
>>>tpye(user)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Which makes me think that authenticate is always returning a NonType to me, because the User object does have the name property.

I've tried to fix it by running the following commands:

```
pipenv uninstall django-heroku
pipenv clean
pipenv install (all packages again)
pipenv lock
```

I've tried to fix it errase DB and created it again and removing the header I created in the settings.py file

As a curious fact, when I try to open the application's database without being connected to the internet, (it's local, so I shouldn't need the internet... and I didn't need it before) I get the following message:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w64Gq.png)

It should not be a problem in my code because I haven't edited anything since the last time it worked, it has to be something related to git bash or dependencies that have been added while following the tutorial....

My files:

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'key'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'home.Usuario'
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'home',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('home.backends.UserAuthentificacionBackend',)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cryptoassistant.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cryptoassistant.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**user model**

```
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text="The name must be between 2 and 12 characters")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True, help_text="The email must be between 5 and 30 characters")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=78)
    change_password_code = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activated_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=15)
    ip = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    last_login = models.DateField(default=now)
    wallets = models.ManyToManyField(Wallet)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin)
    avatar = models.CharField(blank=True,default="bitcoin.png",max_length=15)
    delete_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=9,blank=True)
    two_factors_auth = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    two_factors_auth_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=12,blank=True)
    fingerprint = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)
    private_wallets = models.ManyToManyField(PrivateWallet, blank=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    API_key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Any idea?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi XBoss - is it possible to remove my access from the repository you added me to. :)

Comment: Sure! thanks so much!

Comment: No worries at all - you can find me on twitter @michealjroberts if you need any more help or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authenticate()` verifies a set of credentials. It takes username and password for the default case, checks them against each authentication backend, and returns a User object if the credentials are valid for a backend. It looks like you are sure that the username and password credentials are correct.

However, if the credentials aren’t valid for any backend or if a backend raises `PermissionDenied`, it returns `None`.

So, my hunch as to what is going on:

You have a user model (`Usario`) that you have used to create a User. But the username needed to authenticate your user is not being associated between your custom User model or your BaseAbstract user model. Here's what you need to do:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text="The name must be between 2 and 12 characters")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True, help_text="The email must be between 5 and 30 characters")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=78)
    change_password_code = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activated_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=15)
    ip = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    last_login = models.DateField(default=now)
    wallets = models.ManyToManyField(Wallet)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin)
    avatar = models.CharField(blank=True,default="bitcoin.png",max_length=15)
    delete_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=9,blank=True)
    two_factors_auth = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    two_factors_auth_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=12,blank=True)
    fingerprint = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)
    private_wallets = models.ManyToManyField(PrivateWallet, blank=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    API_key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    # Here you can define any number of methods on your new custom user model that may be useful, for example, sending your user an email:

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        Sends an email to this User.
        '''
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

Then, create a file named `managers.py` in the same directory as your models.py file, and add the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

That should be it, your new authenticate method (once you have created a new User) should work on your custom user model! :)

Disclaimer: you may need to run `$ python manage.py makemigrations` and `$ python manage.py migrate` after adding this code.